# ROS Python Module - Autocompletion doesn't work when self-compiled

Tags: ros, python, ros-melodic, module

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

i have written a package with an python module in it. I can import it in my other packages but VSCode cannot autocomplete functions.

```
from <ros_python_module> import <class>
```

when i click on <ros_python_module>, it goes into an autogenerated "_ *init*_.py" inside of my devel folder. There is no code from me.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# generated from catkin/cmake/template/__init__.py.in
# keep symbol table as clean as possible by deleting all unnecessary symbols
```

Is it possible that catkin build makes a copy of the files and moves them into the devel folder?

Example:
moveit_commander -> from package manager i can autocomplete inside vscode --> compiling by myself and it doesnt autocomplete

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/341418/ros-python-module---autocompletion-doesn%27t-work-when-self-compiled/) by [TobiMiller](https://answers.ros.org/users/32819/tobimiller/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2020-01-10

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [davekroezen](https://answers.ros.org/users/43843/davekroezen/) on 2020-01-10**:
VSCode needs to know where the actual code is. You probably need to edit the configuration file of VSCode or use a plugin that knows where to look for python code in ROS packages and does this for you. Copying the files to where VSCode is now looking doesn't sound like a good idea.

**Comment by [TobiMiller](https://answers.ros.org/users/32819/tobimiller/) on 2020-01-11**:
VSCode knows the PYTHONPATH but how i said, catkin compiles an auto generated init py which is not introspecteable :/

**Comment by [vbs](https://answers.ros.org/users/34727/vbs/) on 2020-09-30**:
Hi Tobi, I'm having the same problem: even though import works, I can't get autocomplete on my IDEs (PyCharm or VSCode) for my custom source modules. I'm wondering if you found a solution for this?

**Comment by [TobiMiller](https://answers.ros.org/users/32819/tobimiller/) on 2020-10-01**:
@vbs
you have to add the folder to your vscode settings.json. "python.autoComplete.extraPaths"

**Comment by [vbs](https://answers.ros.org/users/34727/vbs/) on 2020-10-01**:
Is that the package folder? I added it like this but made no difference:

```
    "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
        "/home/vbs/catkin_ws/src/test_python_import/src/test_python_import"
    ]
```

**Comment by [dcardenasn](https://answers.ros.org/users/41229/dcardenasn/) on 2021-09-28**:
extraPaths should point to the folder that contains a folder with **init**.py file. In my case it was:

```
"python.analysis.extraPaths": [
    "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages",
    "./src/<pkg_name>/src"
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can create a `.env` file with a `PYTHONPATH` variable with all the source paths in it, then reference this file from the `python.envFile` setting in VS code. This path will only be used by the python extension tools and not by the terminal. In this way when running from the terminal you are still running in a "deployed" situation from `devel` but the tools can still find the source files. It isn't the prettiest but it is a work around.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53653083/how-to-correctly-set-pythonpath-for-visual-studio-code
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting#_pylint

---

Originally posted by [tonyp](https://answers.ros.org/users/52598/tonyp/) with karma: 11 on 2020-03-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have tried all the mentioned solutions but none of them worked for me, here is what I ended up with.

My goal is to get Pylance (the better vscode language server) to recognize my ros packages and not default to the devel/... generated file. For this the only important thing is for the package directory (catkin_ws/src/python_package/src/) to be present after the generated (catkin_ws/devel/lib/python3/dist-packages) one in the PYTHONPATH global variable. For some reason pylance (and pyright) always pick the last valid import path when analysing an import. This way custom package code points to the implementation and generated msgs still point to the generated code.

TL;DR

first source devel/setup.bash
then add src/python_package/src to pythonpath

---

Originally posted by [papalotis](https://answers.ros.org/users/88965/papalotis/) with karma: 11 on 2021-11-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1